# Express/Handlebars not displaying expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm building a MEAN app that will utilise a RESTful API and I'm currently working on the client-side stuff. I'm using handlebars as the view engine so I can render expressions etc. but the problem I'm having is that expressions aren't being rendered.

As a starting point I've built simple user authentication into the app using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) which is working fine. Registering/Logging in is working and i'm able to protect my PUT/POST/DELETE API requests in my app by ensuring the user is both logged in and is an administrator. The problem i'm having now is rendering expressions...

The regular expression I'm trying to get working is a starting point is `{{user.username}}` but no matter what I try, it just doesn't work.

**View engine: (app.js)**

```
var hbs;
hbs = exphbs.create({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    layoutsDir: './app/views/layouts',
    partialsDir: './app/views/partials'
});
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
```

**Route: (app.js)**

```
app.get('/admin', Auth.ensureAdmin, function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin');
});
```

**Auth.ensureAdmin (authentication.js)**

```
exports.ensureAdmin = function ensureAdmin (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && req.user.admin === true)
        next();
    else
        res.send(403);
};
```

**admin.hbs (views)**

```
<h1>Welcome, {{user.username}}</h1>
```

**users.js (mongoose schema)**

```
var (dependencies)
...
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    admin: { type: Boolean, required: true }
});

...

var userModel = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
exports.userModel = userModel;
```

Comment: Are you passing in "user" to the template? Shouldn't it be res.render('admin', user); ?

Comment: @MarkRobson I tried that but I get user is not defined when trying to access /admin

Comment: In your route "/admin" you need to do something like if (req.loggedIn) { ... if they are get req.user. Then pass that into the hbs template

Comment: You're right. I wrapped the render function inside `if (req.user) { ... }` then passed in req.user - if you post it as an answer i'll +1

Comment: in fact, i only needed to pass in `req` without the wrap to get user.username working